# using barabasi.game graph on a binary graph dataset

Tags: graph, igraph

I have a binary dataset which is as follows,

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 63 64 65 66 67
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1
 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

The rows are the nodes (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and the columns are the edges (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67 )

I am curious how I can fit a barbasi.game graph for this dataset ? Any advise on this is much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by fitting, because `barabasi.game` does not do any fitting AFAIK.

Comment: @GaborCsardi ) I was wondering if I can use barabasi.game on a dataset like that